# Why does this alert contain undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

This is my code and it gets options from a jsTree checkbox tree list:

```
var level1, r = [];

for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
    r[0] = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text.trim();
    r[1] = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).parents.length;

    if(r[1] == 1) {
       level1 += r[0] + ", ";
       alert(level1);
    }
}
```

The `alert` of the above contains `undefined` along with the correct choices from the checkboxes.  Any idea why I am getting undefined in the output?

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well, for better understanding.

Comment: `var level1;
var r = [];` And `level1 = r[0]+", ";` try this

Comment: Your level1 var is undefined.. assign blank string to it so that you can concatenate

Comment: `var level1,` is `var level1 = undefined,` so you should be initializing it to an empty string.

Comment: `var level1, r = [];` - does that not define level1?

Comment: No.. do you want to assign a blank array to both vars? In that case it Should​ be like var a = b = someval so that it assings the same val to both var.. make sure you define both vars first else the second will be global

Comment: Props to Mr. Alien - I am suitably embarassed..... `var level1 = ''` DOH!!!  Apols all.

Comment: Yeah doing += on something that has no initial value usually breaks.  Using var with commas is allowed though.  `var i, j, k=1, l='hello',` ... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `level1` is undefined when you first try to use it here:

```
level1 += r[0]+", ";
```

That's the same as:

```
level1 = level1 + r[0]+", ";
```

The problem is `level1` undefined the first iteration through and so the text contains `undefined` and concatenating it concatenates `"undefined"` as a string as it is coerced. Initialize it to an empty string:

```
var level1 = "";
```

That way it will not be undefined when you access it.

Comment: @Homer_J and you next question is how to not have a trailing comma. ;)

Comment: @epascarello I thought the same thing xD

Answer (score 0):

**This**

```js
var level1, r = [];

for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
    r[0] = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text.trim();
    r[1] = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).parents.length;

    if(r[1] == 1){
       level1 += r[0]+", ";
       alert(level1);
    }
}
```

Should be

```js
var level1 = '';
   //Or leve1 = []; If you really need it as an array.
var r = [];

for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
    r[0] = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text.trim();
    r[1] = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).parents.length;

    if(r[1] === 1){
       // level1[0] += r[0]+", "; If array.
       level1 += r[0]+", ";
       alert(level1);
      // alert(level1[0]); If array.
    }
}
```

The `level1` is undefined since `level1, r = []` makes `r === []` and `level1 === undefined`.

So I suggest you explicitly declare both variables as shown in the code block above.

Also I fixed comparison operators, [see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: Thanks ArchNoob - appreciated.  String was indeed the issue but, as it happens, the above solves a different issue I was facing elsewhere!

Comment: Awesome! @Homer_J

Comment: "Is an array since you declared it as ..." - where do you see that? They explicitly concatenate a string so it's probably a string

Comment: @AndrewLi Ahh, you are right. I mistakenly thought `var some, some1 = []` makes both some & some1 === []. But it actually makes some === undefined and some1 === []. I updated the answer to fit the corrections. Thanks!